# Show only unique results with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a series of reviews for a professor, I want users to be able to sort reviews based on the class taught.  I have a collection_select but I'm having trouble filtering out duplicates,  so for example if more than one user had a professor for "English" you will just see "English" twice in the list.

This is what I have:

`<%= collection_select(:professor, :id, Review.where(professor_id: @professor.id), :id, :whatclass) %>`

I've seen some solutions saying that I should add `.uniq` but that dosen't seem to do anything.

`<%= collection_select(:professor, :id, Review.where(professor_id: @professor.id).uniq, :id, :whatclass) %>` I'm pretty sure this is not working because it's referring to the Review.id rather than Review.whatclass

Comment: `Review.where(...).select('distinct(whatclass)')`? That's a strange database column name, by the way - I'd have used something like `subject`.

Comment: This works for me.  And I agree with your assessment, I wasn't thinking when I wrote it (it is better than my first idea "classe").

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains duplicates because it has an entry for every *review*, not for every *class taught*, which is not unique for each review. I am not even sure you need to use `collection_select` to render a simple list of unique class names.

In the controller, try:

```
@unique_classes = Review.
  where(professor_id: @professor.id).
  pluck(:whatclass).uniq
```

Here, `pluck` returns an array of just the `whatclass` attributes of every review of the professor. Calling `uniq` on that will drop any duplicates in the array. If you have lots of reviews for each professor, you can get better performance by having the database filter the duplicates:

```
@unique_classes = Review.
  where(professor_id: @professor.id).
  pluck("DISTINCT whatclass")
```

This will generate a `SELECT DISTINCT` query, so the array `pluck` returns will already be unique.

Finally, you can plug this array of `whatclass` values into a simple `select_tag`:

```
select_tag :class_name, options_for_select(@unique_classes)
```

The code above is untested, so it might need some changes to work.

Comment: `.select('distinct(whatclass)')` should perform the uniqueness calculation in SQL, not ruby, which is more performant.

Comment: @SimpleLime I get an error when I attempt this ``undefined method `whatclass' for "English":String``